# search and Replace substring in mac address in a text file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression

Below is extract from the file to be changed: May use awk or sed...any utility is good for pattern matching

```
mgad 1
m-id         50
rf-chan-id   1
base-station-id 00:a0:bc:0c:1b:c1
....
....
mgad 2
....
base-station-id 00:a0:bc:0c:1b:c2
....
....
mgad 3
....
base-station-id 00:a0:bc:0c:1b:c3
....
....
mgad 4
base-station-id 00:a0:bc:0c:1b:c4
```

I have to edit mac address in the 5th position from 
00:a0:bc:0c:XX:c3 to 00:a0:bc:0c:18:c3
for multiple lines in the file. PN: 5th position can be variable,needs to be changed to "18"

I tried this:

```
sed -En ' s/^\( base-station-id.* [0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\:[0-9A-Fa-f]\:[0-9A-Fa-f]\:[0-9A-Fa-f]\:\)[0-9A-Fa-f]+\(\:.*\)$/\118\2/p; '
```

Please help with correct regex pattern matching and replace with desired change in substring in mac address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the leading portion; allow any two characters in the 5th position of the MAC, then capture the trailing portion, and replace it with the 1st captured group, the text `18`, and the 2nd captured group:

```
sed 's/\(base-station-id ..:..:..:..:\)..\(:..\)/\118\2/' < input > output
```

Comment: I get an error:                                                                      `code` sed -En 's/\( base-station-id ..:..:..:..:\)..\(:..\)/\118\2/p' file.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 53: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: Escape the parens

Comment: sed -En 's/\( base-station-id ..:..:..:..:\)..\(:..\)/\118\2/p' file.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 53: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: No need for -E here, either.

Comment: Works without -E